# Bootstrap carousel moving issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap carousel just like following

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h

- when click the arrow it seems it rotate once to get the next image
- I want to click and get next one without rotating. since I am showing 3 graph images at once. So it clearly shows rotate and get next one.
- can anybody help me to get like slide changing without rotating

I tried replacing  'data-ride="carousel"' to 'data-ride="slide"'; but it was not success

Comment: I found the answer , I simply change class="carousel slide" to class="carousel". then it works as I wanted

Answer (score 2):

**Its Working Very Fine By Changing carousel To  `data-ride="slide"`.. Where You Will Get Problem ??**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works fine, But i wanted to get next slide without rotating, in w3shool example it has only 1 image at once. but my one has 3 images at once. So it seems rotating one round and get the other one

Comment: Can you give me some demo site .. `next slide without rotating`  is little bit confusing  `but my one has 3 images at once` . :(

Comment: ok .. are you taking about .. Rotation Slider .. try this one http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/RotatingImageSlider/

Comment: try this,  http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h. And change the class="carousel slide" to class="carousel". There is a bit difference.